# Getting value from s:select inside an iteration

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am iterating a list object in jsp, I want to get the `<s:select>` value when submitting the form.
My jsp is like this:

```html
<s:iterator value="listeTypeEvent" status="event">
    <tr>         
        <td>
            <s:select id = "criticite" 
                    list = "criticite" 
                    name = "degreCriticite"  
                   value = "%{event.degreCriticite}"/>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <s:select id = "famlle"  
                    list = "listFamille" 
                    name = "familleEvent.idFamille"  
                 listKey = "idFamille" 
               listValue = "libelleFamille" 
                   value = "%{event.idFamille}"/>
        </td>  
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm a problem like this, but I'm not pass value, my problem is with list properties ... It is in action class but it's don't arrive for render

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the code in the question is confusing `status` (that instantiates an [IteratorStatus](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) object, and does not have `degreCriticite` nor `idFamille` attributes) with `var` (that instantiates a variable containing the current element in the iteration).

Another minor error is that `id` must be unique in an HTML page.

The missing piece to send back a value of an element created inside an iteration is the creation of an index (through the help of the aforamentioned IteratorStatus object):

```xml
<s:iterator value="listeTypeEvent" var="event" status="ctr">
    <tr>         
        <td>
            <s:select id = "criticite_%{#ctr.index}" 
                    list = "criticite" 
                    name = "degreCriticite[%{#ctr.index}]"  
                   value = "%{event.degreCriticite}"/>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <s:select id = "famlle_%{#ctr.index}"  
                    list = "listFamille" 
                    name = "familleEvent[%{#ctr.index}].idFamille"
                 listKey = "idFamille" 
               listValue = "libelleFamille" 
                   value = "%{event.idFamille}"/>
        </td>  
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```